# How did Enfys Nest and the Cloud-Riders get from planet to planet?

Tags: star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

During *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, we see [Enfys Nest](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Enfys_Nest) and their [Cloud-Riders](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cloud-Riders) on a number of different planets. And yet we only ever see them travel by what appear to be [swoop bikes](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Swoop).

Working under the obvious assumption that they aren't simply flying these bikes directly from world to world, do we know what they use for transportation? Clearly they would need something capable of transporting not only them and their bikes, but presumably a cargo container as well. But the movie doesn't appear to address this.

Comment: [Force Portal](http://swfanon.wikia.com/wiki/Force_Portal). That lady with freckles all over her face was actually a Jedi. You'll see her in upcoming movies.

Comment: @Solo - wait what?

Comment: @RedCaio I have an insider source. Trust me on this one..

Comment: @Solo that looks more like a D&D Portable Hole or Bag of Holding than a Stargate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They travel aboard a (hyperspace capable) carrier ship called the *Aerie*, according to the [Solo: A Star Wars Story The Official Guide](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Solo:_A_Star_Wars_Story_The_Official_Guide)

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>*"Enfys Nest leads the [Cloud-Riders](https://www.starwars.com/databank/cloud-riders) on strikes. The nomadic group travel aboard a carrier ship, the Aerie.*</sup></sub>
> <sub><sup>The ship rarely lands, since the swoop bikes can launch from altitudes of 400 kilometers."</sup></sub>

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Good find, and thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An alternate answer from an alternate universe. ;-) *[The Art of Solo: A Star Wars Story](https://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Art_of_Solo:_A_Star_Wars_Story)* concept art book introduced *the Buckshot* as the vessel that carried Enfys Nest's Cloud-Riders from planet to planet. The ship was specifically designed to fire out the speeder bikes, and it was originally planned to be used in the train sequence. Unfortunately, the idea never made it to the big screen, and the ship was only later re-introduced as *the Aerie*.

[image]