# How did Kylo Ren travel to the other planet in the TIE fighter?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

Near the end in amongst the battle, Kylo Ren lands next to his ship that Rey stole. I understand that at a stretch (or through the will of the Force) Kylo found a TIE Fighter in the wreck he was in, but to my understanding those TIEs would not have had hyperdrives, so how did he travel that far without a carrier ship? I suppose I'm guessing/assuming that he travelled on his own (Solo if you will), and not with his Star Destroyer, as the Knights who travelled with him on his Star Destroyer were already at the destination. But if the Force willed him to find the TIE Fighter, why not a shuttle with a hyperdrive? It would be iconic enough to use in the film, surely.

How did Kylo Ren travel to another system in a civil war era TIE Fighter with no hyperdrive or carrier ship?

Answer (score 9):

While a lot of this is conjecture the most obvious answer is that this was one of the new tie fighters that has hyperdrive (as seen at the start of the movie) and he got it from his own starship which he was on when he arrived at Endor. Even though he turned back to the light side at that moment he could have called up to his ship, had it pick him up and then taken a tie fighter claiming he was chasing after Rey.

Comment: It's made clear to the audience that he's using an Imperial era TIE fighter he found on the wreckage of the Death Star II.

Comment: How is this made clear? He sees Rey escape in his Tie Fighter and then the next scene you see he is landing, we didn't see where he got the TIE Fighter from, it also looks identical to the Lightspeed enabled TIE Fighters seen chasing the Falcon at the start of the movie and these where not imperial era Tie Fighters.

Comment: https://screenrant.com/star-wars-rise-skywalker-kylo-ren-exegol-tie-fighter/ that article also states that he must have got the fighter from the First Order although that article states that Tie Fighters are not equipped with Hyperdrives, which they are because they are shown to be at the start of the movie

Comment: The coloration of the TIE Fighter that landed next to Luke's X-wing matches that of Imperial era models, not First Order. TIE/fo are black with white wing panels. The one he arrived in was clearly grey with darker wing panels, implying it was an Imperial TIE.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is that Ren traveled in a carrier ship and then took a TIE fighter down to the surface. [Raider class](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Raider-class_corvette) ships would have been available during the late Empire era and one could plausibly have survived the wreck of the Death Star II (especially if we assume that an Empire-era TIE fighter also survived). These ships carry a small number of fighters each, enough for Ren to pack along one (or use one that was already in the hangar).

Several decades previously, Enfys Nest had apparently [traveled](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/189459/70477) on an "unseen" carrier. Although the *Solo* film itself only ever shows the team's speeder bikes, supplementary material establishes that they do have a carrier out there. This provides some precedent that there may be additional off-screen ships that drive the plot in some manner. There is also the matter of the AT-AT walkers that participated in the Battle of Hoth. While Episode V never shows us exactly how they landed, we later discover through other media that the Empire does have specialized walker lander craft that were likely used on Hoth.

Answer (score 3):

Ben was able to find an Imperial-era ["Scout-Class" TIE Fighter](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/TIE_scout) in the Death Star's wreckage. It apparently has a working (if crappy) hyperdrive.

> **It had taken Ben Solo too long to climb through the ruins of the Death Star in search of a hangar bay, even longer to find an old scout-class TIE and coax it into flying for him. He’d then followed Rey’s transmitted tracking markers toward Exegol,** but the scout’s barely functioning navicomputers had taken a wrong turn, and he’d found himself grinding through unknown rough space. It had taken all his concentration to correct his course and get back on track.
>
> All that had been the easy part.
>
> He landed his TIE scout beside an old Rebellion X-wing. He couldn’t help pausing to stare at the two ships. Old enemies, parked side by side.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: Expanded Edition](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

Confirmed [via twitter](https://twitter.com/missingwords/status/1233908764320915457) by Matt Martin of the Lucasfilm Story Group

> That one is more confusing but the novel establishes it as a TIE scout, **which apparently had a hyperdrive.**